# Which C++ library provides a map with a key of any type that does not enforce implementing a compare function?

Tags: c++

What I'm looking for is something like this:

```
class my_class { ... };
typedef LIBRARY_NAME::map<my_class> my_class_map;
```

thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to implement a comparison (less-than) function?

Comment: @JohnZwinck: Perhaps there is no easy way to define a strict weak ordering for the OP's key class.

Comment: Sure, or perhaps the OP has a third-party class and doesn't realize he can write his own comparison function even if the third-party code lacks it.  Could be lots of reasons....

Answer (score 5):

`std::unordered_map`. But it requires a hash function to be defined instead.

Comment: That's mass o menos the same problem

Comment: @Ezra: Well, an associative container needs some way of performing key lookup.  That's unavoidable.

Comment: At a minimum, you need the equivalent of operator== just to recognize which key is which. If that's all you have, you can't do any better than O(n) lookup, at which point rolling your own container on top of std::list or std::deque is a trivial exercise anyway. If you can't define operator< and you can't define a hash, that's really all that's left.

Comment: thanks, I can apply md5 or any general purpose hash function on my objects, but I kind of hoped that there is some standard library that hides the details.